# How can I call a program 100 times in a CL?

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I want to call a program in a CL for 100 times to measure up the call times with different program settings.

Maybe something like this?

```
DOFOR      VAR(&INT) FROM(0) TO(99)
CALL       PGM(TProg) PARM(&Parm)
ENDDO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do this kind of testing, I pass in the number of iterations as a parameter.

You should have enough iterations so that the call with the quickest settings takes at least half a minute, to help cancel out the extra work like getting the timestamps. Having the number of iterations be a parameter makes it easier to do this.

To get a timestamp in CL, you can use RTVSYSVAL QDATETIME.

```
dcl &before type(*char) len(20)      
dcl &after type(*char) len(20)       

rtvsysval QDATETIME rtnvar(&before)  
--- do the loop
rtvsysval QDATETIME rtnvar(&after)   
sndpgmmsg &before
sndpgmmsg &after
```

The timestamps aren't very readable (20180203143253529956 which means 2018-02-03-14.32.53.529956). You might want to do some substringing to make them more readable, or even do some calculations to get the number of seconds between the two timestamps.

**Update to answer the question about how to substring:**

Me, I would just write an RPG program to get the difference between the two timestamps.

```
**free
dcl-pi *n;
   t1 char(20) const;
   t2 char(20) const;
   diffSeconds packed(7:2);
end-pi;
dcl-s ts1 timestamp;
dcl-s ts2 timestamp;
ts1 = %timestamp(t1 : *iso0);
ts2 = %timestamp(t2 : *iso0);
diffSeconds = %diff (ts1 : ts2 : *seconds : 2);
return;
```

If you don't want to use RPG, or you cannot, then here's how you could use substring and concatenation in CL to produce a more readable timestamp.

```
dcl &prtBefore type(*char) len(26)                      

chgvar &prtBefore (%sst(&before  1 4) *tcat '-' *tcat + 
                   %sst(&before  5 2) *tcat '-' *tcat + 
                   %sst(&before  7 2) *tcat '-' *tcat + 
                   %sst(&before  9 2) *tcat '.' *tcat + 
                   %sst(&before 11 2) *tcat '.' *tcat + 
                   %sst(&before 13 2) *tcat '.' *tcat + 
                   %sst(&before 15 6))                  
sndpgmmsg &prtBefore
```

Comment: Thanks a lot great idea. How would you substringing it?

Comment: I will update my reply to answer the substring question , since there's no formatting in an ordinary reply.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that will work. How are you going to measure performance?